# Remove hyper-v virtual switch extensions adapters from device manager

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8.1, vswitch

After reading the solution to [this](https://serverfault.com/q/584316/320819) question I still cannot solve my problem.

In my device manager I still see this virtual switch, but it's not present in my hyper-v manager and using the powershell command doesn't show anything at all.

I already tried removing the hyper-v feature from windows and adding it back, without success.

How can I remove this device from my computer?

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: OK, I see that this is a Hyper-V host, so what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @joeqwerty, I updated my question to be more explicit.

Comment: So you removed the Hyper-V role? Why did you reinstall it if you're trying to remove these devices? Have you tried removing the Hyper-V role and then rebooting the server?

Comment: I am trying to remove the virtual switch because I can not add other virtual switches, and this one doesn't work. I tried removing hyper-v (feature) and then adding it back, with restarts in between and even trying to remove it while hyper-v wasn't installed

Comment: What happens when you try to create a new virtual switch? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: no error messages, it just hangs and I have to quit hyper console

Comment: OK, I'm not understanding this. Why are you trying to remove this device then? Are you able to create a new virtual switch?

Comment: I am trying to remove the virtual switch because I can not add other virtual switches, and this one doesn't work, it doesn't connect to the network

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36475/discussion-between-davejal-and-joeqwerty).